# Usage of consecutive variable names in a script

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to do some simple calculations with variables in an `script.sh`, in the same directory there is a folder called `New Folder2`. So, I want to enter into the folder and save a text file.

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
foldername='New Folder'
number=1
number=$number+1
cd $foldername$number
echo '$number' > number.txt
```

But then I only get the file `number.txt` in the same directory `./` with `1+1` not the actual sum. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integers, use arithmetic expansion:  $(( EXPR ))

```
num=$((num1 + num2))
num=$((num + 1))
```

Comment: It only works for integers? And what can I do for other types of variables?

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar you can use your way with strings
 a='hello'
 b='world'
 c=$a$b
 echo $c
 > helloworld

Comment: To concatenate/"add" strings you can just do something like $string="$string$anotherstring". Also, an alternative to the arithmetic expansion would be to use `let number=$number+1`, though I think the `$(( ))` syntax is more easily readable..

Answer (score 1):

Look at 4th and 5th line!

```
#!/bin/bash
foldername='New Folder'
number=1
number=$((number+1))
cd "$foldername$number"
echo '$number' > number.txt
```